# DL360 G7 - iLo3 API

Tags: hp

I just receive proliant dl360 g7 so it is iLo3.

i would like to know if there an api for ilo3. I saw many SDK and tutorial but only for iLo4 and up.

the URL for iLo4 is pretty simple, somethings like .../redfish/v1...

but can't find for iLo

im looking to develop my own manager in PHP  (curl call) so i can manage remotely by iLo3..

anyone have any idea ? What is URL api call for ilo3?

Or is there any other way to call ilo3

thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Please reference: https://seveas.github.io/python-hpilo/

This is a good way to manage automation around multiple ILO versions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, the link you provided mention “ All RILOE II/iLO versions up to and including iLO 5” in the compatibility. I can’t even find the RESTful URL to call API for iLo3…

Answer (score 0):

It look like iLo2 and iLo3 doesn’t have restful API and need to use SNMP protocol to communicate with server.

> Configuring insight management integration Navigate to the
> Administration→Management page. Configure the HP System Management
> Homepage (HP SMH). This value sets the browser destination of the
> Insight Agent link on iLO pages.Enter the IP address or DNS name of
> the host server. The protocol (https://) and portnumber (:2381) are
> added automatically to the IP address or DNS name to allow accessfrom
> iLO. If the URL is set through another method (for example, HPQLOCFG),
> click the browserrefresh button to display the updated URL. Select the
> Level of Data Returned. Optional: Click View XML Reply to view the
> response that is returned to HP SIM when itrequests iLO management
> processor identification using the provided address. Click Apply to
> save the changes.

Source: https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=a00045473en_us&docLocale=en_US